# Feynman's proof for law governing 'simplified' refracting surface

Tags: optics, refraction

In Feynman's [27th lecture](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_27.html), he explains how we can find the equation for a refracting surface by the use of fermat's principle of least time. To do this , he first introduces the following result:
[image]

$$ h^2 = d^2 - s^2 = (d+s)(d-s)$$

And, approximating $ d+s \approx 2s$ and $s-d =\delta$, we can get:

$$ h^2 = 2s \Delta$$

Rearrange:

$$ \Delta = \frac{h^2}{2s}$$

Now, comes my doubt, he shows the following diagram:

[image]

Basically air-glass mediums seperated by a refracting surface, speed of light as $1$ in air and $ \frac{1}{n}$ in glass. Under a lot of assumptions and simplifications, he proceeds with the following arguement for deriving the refraction formula for curved surface refraction:

> Supposing P is close to the axis, we drop a perpendicular$ PQ$ such that the height $PQ$ is $h$. For a moment, we imagine that the surface is a plane passing through $P$. In that case, the time needed to go from $O $to$ P$ would exceed the time from $O$ to $Q$, and also, the time from $P $to $O′$ would exceed the time from Q to O′. But that is why the glass must be curved, because the total excess time must be compensated by the delay in passing from V to Q! Now the excess time along route OP is $\frac{h^2}{2s}$, and the excess time on the other route is $\frac{nh^2}{2s′}$. This excess time, which must be matched by the delay in going along VQ, differs from what it would have been in a vacuum, because there is a medium present. In other words, the time to go from V to Q is not as if it were straight in the air, but it is slower by the factor n, so that the excess delay in this distance is then $(n−1)VQ$. And now, how large is $VQ$? If the point C is the center of the sphere and if its radius is $R$, we see by the same formula that the distance $VQ $is equal to $ \frac{h^2}{2R}$. Therefore we discover that the law that connects the distances $s$ and $s′$, and that gives us the radius of curvature R of the surface that we need, is

> $$ \frac{h^2}{2s} + \frac{nh^2}{2s'}= (n-1) \frac{h^2}{2R}$$

I'm having a bit of toruble of how it was found that $VQ= \frac{h^2}{2r}$. I can't visualize the contruction in 27-1 for this case, am I missing something like an approximation made?

---

Btw for what it's worth, here is how I see the excess distance for OP and O'P

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with a very smart friend, I figured out how to do it. To understand, we note a key idea in the previous paragraph:

> The farther ones may deviate if they want to, unfortunately, because the ideal surface is complicated, and we use instead a spherical surface with the right curvature at the axis. It is so much easier to fabricate a sphere than other surfaces that it is profitable for us to find out what happens to rays striking a spherical surface, supposing that only the rays near the axis are going to be focused perfectly. Those rays which are near the axis are sometimes called paraxial rays, and what we are analyzing are the conditions for the focusing of paraxial rays. We shall discuss later the errors that are introduced by the fact that all rays are not always close to the axis.

So, we see that this discussion as (also said so in the title) is about spherical surface. Now, notice that

$$ CP= CQ + \Delta$$

And, if it is approximately spherical since $CV$ and $CP$ are radiuses:

$$ CV=CP= CQ+\Delta$$

Now, $$CV=CQ+VQ$$ hence:

$$ VQ=\Delta= \frac{h^2}{2R}$$